# How can i download robotium eclipse plugin?

Tags: automation, eclipse-plugin, robotium

Can't download robotium Eclipse plugin, getting the error shown: [image: screenshot]. 
What could be the reason?

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Where did you find this update site reference? it seems to not be used anymore.

have you tried to install it from the Eclipse Marketplace?
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/robotium-recorder

regards,